# Ways of calculating coefficient of performance (COP)

Tags: thermodynamics

Calculating COP with the help of:

- Power (i.e. a whole plant)
- Enthalpies (with refrigerant)
- Using Carnot's COP as a comparison (this is mainly theoretical).

The refrigerant could be R134a as a processing medium, where it acts as different temperatures on the source. The source in this case is an immersion heater, even though realistically, we'd use seawater.

I accidentally pressed *enter*, which published the question. However, I meant to say that, how can I calculate the COP with the help of those three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about an actual power plant as a whole (I am not conversant in power plant engineering). But I would guess you would need to apply the general definition of COP. The COP is defined as the ratio of the desired heat transfer to the work required to make the transfer. What is considered to be the "desired heat transfer" depends on whether you are looking at it as a heat pump or as an air conditioner/refrigerator.

$$COP_{HP}=\frac{Q_H}{W}$$

$$COP_{AC}=\frac{Q_L}{W}$$

and since $W=Q_{H}-Q_{L}$

$$COP_{HP}=\frac{Q_H}{Q_{H}-Q_L}$$

$$COP_{HP}=\frac{Q_L}{Q_{H}-Q_L}$$

Where $Q_H$ is the heat transfer to the higher temperature environment and $Q_L$ is the heat transfer out of the low temperature environment.

For the Carnot heat pump/refrigerator the COP only depends on the high and low temperature environment temperatures, $T_H$ and $T_L$, or for Carnot

$$COP_{HP}=\frac{T_H}{(T_{H}-T_{L})}$$

$$COP_{AC}=\frac{T_L}{(T_{H}-T_{L})}$$

An example of using enthalpies is the reversible Rankine refrigeration cycle. In this case

$$COP_{HP}=\frac{h_{1}-h_4}{h_{2}-h_1}$$

$$COP_{AC}=\frac{h_{2}-h_3}{h_{2}-h_1}$$

Where

$h_1$ is the enthalpy at the evaporator output

$h_2$ is the enthalpy at the compressor input

$h_3$ is the enthalpy at the condenser output

$h_4$ is the enthalpy at the evaporator input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, sir. What a delight. I am still new to COP and the reversible Rankine refrigeration cycle, it's frustrating to not be able to understand this fully.

Comment: @Qwin So, you found the answer to be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, sir. I upvoted with great admiration of your knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: @Qwin I only asked because you didn’t press the “accept” button. New contributors are often unaware of it

Comment: Where can I find it, sir?

Comment: @Qwin your should see it below my answer

Comment: I don't know, but I think it's the unchecked "check" symbol. I clicked it, hopefully it "accepts", now.

Comment: Thank you it did

Comment: Sir, if you don't mind me asking as I've got you here and since you've been very helpful to me:

I was wondering, what kind of measurements would you need (pressure and temperature on the refrigerant) to sketch the process in the refrigerant diagram? We wouldn't need to know the flow of the refrigerant, since the flow is all the same in the whole process.

Comment: @Qwin Use a pressure-enthalpy diagram for the refrigerant (e.g., refrigerant HFC-134a) and plot the processes for the four enthalpies I gave in the answer.

Comment: Hello, sir. This will be the last question, I have truly appreciated your help. If you don't mind helping me with one more concerns I have:

How does heat patron temperature; heat temperature; coldwater temperature; hotwater temperature; flow of heatwater (kg/s); pressure in evaporator (gauge pressure); pressure in condenser (gauge pressure); temperature in evaporator and compressor; temperature before valve; and power of the compressor come into play here? 

I understand that I might be asking too much of you. I understand if you don't have time to help this time.

Comment: What do you mean by "patron"?

Comment: An electrical heating coil of some kind that is installed in a tank of water, or an electric boiler without a dispenser.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand your question. What do you mean by heat temperature, cold water temperature, etc. The working fluid in Ac Nd heat pumps is a refrigerant, not water

Comment: I understand. You must excuse me, I am busy; I will be back ASAP to further clarify.

Comment: Hello, I'm back. Don't you need cold water temperature to be able to also calculate efficiency? The "patron" is a heat source.

Comment: As for the cold water temperature, you know how there's two temperature values? As in one is for the hot reservoir $T_H$ and the other is the outlet of the cooling water $T_C$.

Comment: You need the low temperature of the refrigerant (not water) in the evaporator where the refrigerant takes in heat from the environment being cooled, and the temperature of the refrigerant in the condenser which transfers heat out of the refrigerant to the environment being heated.

Comment: Kind of resurrecting this question, once again. Your answer has been very helpful. I came back to clarify a few things since there was a bit of a language barrier occurring for me. By a heat patron I meant something that can act as a reservoir, where we can manually change the temperature of both the sink and source. You still helped, sir.

As for the water cycle, how would I go on about solving the heat with the help of $Q=mc\Delta t$? I would need $$COP_{HP}=\frac{Q_H}{W}$$, but I am not sure how to go on about it.

Comment: $T_H$ and $T_L$ are the environments to be cooled or heated and consist of air, not water. Are you asking about using heat pumps or refrigerators to heat or cool water?

Comment: I am referring to a heat pump. Let's pick two simple temperatures only for the efficiency of a Carnot heat pump, 0 °C and 45 °C, respectively for the heat source and heat sink. We can use these values for Carnot efficiency as a comparison. As for the water it is used to calculate how much heat is produced, let's say temperatures of 7.8 °C and 42.6 °C, cold water and warm water, that is. This is only experimentally. However, I am not sure how to get the mass or the transferred heat, for that matter. Please note, I already know the compressor power.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 7.8 C and 42.6 C water. Do you mean using heat pump to pull heat from water initially at 45 C cooling it to 42.6 C and heating  water initially at 0 C to 45 C?

Comment: You can use the water temperatures to calculate the condenser power.

Comment: I assume by condenser power you are referring to the rate of heat extraction. If that's the case, it is simply the difference between the entering and exiting enthalpies

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sir. As for the p-h diagram for R134a, why do I get different enthalpy values at some states? For example, at the inlet of the compressor, I have 6.2 °C and 2.8 bar (evaporator pressure), from observation I see it's around 405 kJ/kg. Now, using a website where it calculates it for you it gives me 341.70 kJ/kg. As for state 2, compressor exit is 69,6 °C and condenser pressure 10 bar, I see almost 450-455 kJ/kg and the website gives also almost the same value. Exit of condenser (state 3) at 31.6 °C, I see 240-244 kJ/kg as well as the website does. Why is state 1 different?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is going WAY beyond the scope of the original question. I suggest you post a new question. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I figured. Thanks for all your help, Bob!